# How to reformat this datetime without regex in Google Sheets?

Tags: regex, datetime, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In Google Sheets i want to reformat this datetime `Mon, 08 Mar 2021 10:57:15 GMT` into this `08/03/2021`.

Using RegEx i achieve the goal with

```
=to_date(datevalue(REGEXEXTRACT("Mon, 08 Mar 2021 10:57:15 GMT","\b[0-9]{2}\s\D{3}\s[0-9]{4}\b")))
```

But how can i do it *without* RegEx? This datetime format seems to be a classic one - can it really be, that no onboard formula can't do it? I rather think, i miss the right knowledge here...

Comment: If the string is always formatted the same you could just use `=DATEVALUE(MID(A1,6,11))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following formula and **format as date**

```
=TRIM(LEFT(INDEX(SPLIT(K13,","),,2),12))*1
```

*(do adjust according to your locale)*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use Custom Script.

### Example:

**Code:**

```
function formatDate(date) {
  return Utilities.formatDate(new Date(date), "GMT", "dd/MM/YYYY") 
}
```

**Formula in **B1**:** `=formatDate(A1)`

**Output:**

[image]

### Reference:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)